# ScissorRectange and ScaleMatrix

Tags: xna

I have worked through the examples of turning on ScissorTestEnable and ScissorRectangle.  It works fine.  However, when I apply a ScaleMatrix the clipping no longer seems to work.  Are these supposed to work together?

Comment: You mean you're applying some scaling to something you render? What is being scaled here?

Comment: Sorry, trying to do too many things at once.  It is a 2D game.  I create a screen for each player.  The opponent screen is scaled and placed(usually top right) of the player screen.  I want to be able to clip graphics on this scaled screen.  The ScaleMatrix works for sprites and graphics that I draw so that they are correct, but they are no longer clipped after scaling and 'bleed' past the reduced screen.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem . I'm really intressted please

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using SpriteBatch, correct? It seems to me that Shawn Hargreaves' [comment on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.scissorrectangle.aspx) is probably the answer you're looking for. Have you tried moving the call that sets the scissor rectangle around to see if it starts working? I tried looking at the decompiled sources of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics - but I couldn't find any relation between GraphicsDevice.set_ScissorRectangle and SpriteBatch's flushing methods. :S

If it doesn't work, you could also try to replace the scale and scissor with a modified projection and viewport call and then render the objects in each player's screen.

Comment: Yes I am using SpriteBatch and I make the call to the GraphicsDevice just before creating the SpriteBatch.  Based on whether I want the opponent's screen to be full sized or reduced in the upper corner is whether I call Spritebatch with a ScaleMatrix or not.  When I call it without the ScaleMatix the ScissorRectangle works.  When I invoke the ScaleMatrix teh ScissorRectangle does not.  I assume it is my error, but did not want to spend a lot of time chasing this if the two did not play nicely together.